# How can I get around differences in column types when using unpivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I am having problems using unpivot on columns, that are not the exact same datatype, and I can't figure out how to convert the columns on the fly, because the syntax for UNPIVOT does not seem to support it.

Consider this example:

```
DECLARE @People TABLE
(PersonId int, Firstname varchar(50), Lastname varchar(50))
-- Load Sample Data
INSERT INTO @People VALUES (1, 'Abe', 'Albertson')
INSERT INTO @People VALUES (2, 'Benny', 'Boomboom')

SELECT PersonId, ColumnName, Value FROM @People
UNPIVOT
(
  ColumnName FOR 
  Value IN (FirstName, LastName)
)
```

The result would be this:

```
PersonId    ColumnName        Value
----------- ----------------- ----------------
1           Abe               Firstname
1           Albertson         Lastname
2           Benny             Firstname
2           Boomboom          Lastname
```

Everything is unicorns and rainbows. Now I change the datatype of Lastname to varchar(25) and everything breaks. The output is:

> The type of column "Lastname" conflicts with the type of other columns
>   specified in the UNPIVOT list.

How can I get around this and convert everything to say a varchar(50) on the fly, without tampering with the actual data types on the table?

SqlFiddle working example (same datatype): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3719

SqlFiddle broken example (diff datatypes): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5dca13/1

Comment: The most obvious way to do this is perform the `CAST` in a subquery, then `UNPIVOT` the result of that. Interested to hear if there is a more elegant approach though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot convert inside the UNPIVOT syntax but you can convert the data inside a subquery similar to the following:

```
select PersonId, ColumnName, Value  
from
(
  select personid, 
    firstname, 
    cast(lastname as varchar(50)) lastname
  from People
) d
unpivot
(
  Value FOR 
  ColumnName in (FirstName, LastName)
) unpiv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5dca13/13)

Another way to do this would be to use CROSS APPLY, depending on your version of SQL Server you can use CROSS APPLY with VALUES or UNION ALL:

```
select PersonId, ColumnName, Value  
from People
cross apply
(
  select 'firstname', firstname union all
  select 'lastname', cast(lastname as varchar(50))
) c (ColumnName, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5dca13/10).

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, col2, Answer, Question_Col
from ( 
SELECT 
col1,
col2,
col3,
CAST(col4 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) col4,
```

-- Note: Here datatype should be same as that of previous columns

```
CAST(col5 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) col5
FROM Table_Name )a
unpivot
(
Answer
for Question_Col in (
col3,
col4,
col5
)
) unpiv;
```